# Secure Connection for SMTP

Tags: powershell, ssl, smtp

I have this simple script that sends an email using SMTP.

```bsh
$EmailFrom = "from@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "to@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Reports"
$Body = "Please see attachments"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SMTPClient($SMTPServer, 587)
$User = "from"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "Password" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $User, $PWord
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $Credential -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject
```

I am facing an issue using `-UseSsl`.

Using it, gives me the error

> Send-MailMessage : Server does not support secure connections.

Not using it, gives me the error

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 4sm4306203pav.33 - gsmtp

Answer (score 1):

`Net.Mail.SmtpClient` and `Send-MailMessage` are 2 ways to the same end: sending mail from PowerShell. However, in your sample code the `SmtpClient` statement just creates a client without actually doing anything with it while the `Send-MailMessage` statement doesn't specify the correct port (587), so the default port (25) is used instead.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849925.aspx):

> **-Port<Int32>**
>   Specifies an alternate port on the SMTP server. The default value is 25, which is the default SMTP port. This parameter is available in Windows PowerShell 3.0 and newer releases.

Change

```
...
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SMTPClient($SMTPServer, 587)
$User = "from"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "Password" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $User, $PWord
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $Credential -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject
```

to

```
...
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$User = "from"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "Password" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $User, $PWord
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port 587 -UseSsl -Credential $Credential -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject
```

and your code should work.

Comment: You may still run into an issue if the mail server requires TLS 1.2 instead of allowing TLS 1.0...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785662/why-does-send-mailmessage-fail-to-send-using-starttls-over-port-587